# Column shows non-printable values, how do I see what they are?

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe

I have a row in my table where I cannot understand the content. The field is a CHAR (8) and the data should be obviously alphanumeric, but in the result of the select below several "dots" appear according to the first line below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (USERID)
FROM USER;
---------------
USERID
---------------
........
AC25
A25A
A25X
```

It turns out that I cannot get this line in a specific select, it does not return a result in the query below:

```
SELECT USERID
FROM USER
WHERE USERID = '........';
---------------
USERID
---------------
```

Can you tell me if there is any clause where you select this WEIRD given from this line?

I've tried low-value but DB2 does not accept, I've never seen this in a table.
Can you help me find options for this case other than putting together a query with "not in"?

Comment: what happens if you select from another table?

Comment: I don't have a DB2 installed, but can it be that the `.....` is just the output on the console for an actually empty value (or a null value)? Maybe you try something like `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userid = ''` or `where userid is null`...

Comment: Another suggestion would be to add `ascii(userid)` to the items you're selecting. That will give you the ASCII value of the first character (assuming the field isn't `null`).

Comment: was wondering if that's a progress indicator since he's on mainframe :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dots likely represent non-displayable characters.

try looking at the hex values

```
select distinct
  userid, hex(userid)
from user
```

You could then use hex literal to select just that row...

```
select *
from user
where userid = x'C3C8C1D9D3C5E2'
```

Comment: Charles, thank you very much
With your suggestion I actually confirmed it was a low-value or hex (00)
Now I can do the query with where below and select exactly the record.
    SELECT USERID
    FROM USER
    WHERE USERID = x'0000000000000 ';
Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Thanks. You already had my vote, and I'll remove this when the "Last seen" on your profile is after the time of this one...